# Blender 2.81 3D Corner Axis Gizmo thingy disappears when using shortcut move/scale/rotate

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hey guys! I'm used to using G/S/R to move/scale/rotate things. In previous versions the corner gizmo stayed visible at all times so I can further use X/Y/Z to precisely control which direction I want to to move at. Now the gizmo disappears. Any idea what to toggle to make it show?

Without it I'm just guessing which of the XYZ I have to press.